# grails 3 spring security boot starter login page customization

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, spring-boot, grails-3.0

Is it possible to customize the login gsp page for the starter security plugin? 
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security
I read about adding grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp but that made no difference.

Comment: What version of spring security plugin are you using? The auth.gsp is part of the spring-security-core.

Comment: @Aramiti in application.yml there is: compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security”
.gradle lists spring-boot-starter-security-1.2.7.RELEASE

Comment: Adding `grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp` will customize `spring-security-core`, which you are not using. Try to find which gsp(s) are being used, if any, in `spring-boot-starter-security` and add them to your `grails-app/views`. Make sure you use the same folder structure as your plugin, otherwise you can't customize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Grails 3, then you probably would find it easier to use the Grails plugin, rather than trying to use the spring boot starter directly. In your gradle build, put:

`compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:<version>'`

If you run the provided starter script, then the necessary grails config values will be placed in `application.groovy` for you to adjust to your needs.  The docs for the plugin are quite good:  https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/, and once you see how the plugin works, the Spring documentation becomes easier to use in the context of Grails (for example, all the spring bean config you might want to do based on Spring's docs you do in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` using the bean builder DSL.

If you use this plugin then all the spring wiring will be done for you, and the override of the login page's gsp should work as advertised.

If you don't want to use the Grails plugin, then perhaps looking at the source for the plugin will give you the information you need to wire in the spring package yourself (since that's what the plugin does).  Most of the spring  wiring work takes place right in the plugin file `SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy`

Comment: very helpful; used the suggested plugin vs spring-boot-starter-security; built up to the functionality provided by spring-boot-starter-security and was able to replace auth.gsp as suggested